# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 6 from 1 for 'conv1d_2/convolution/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,5], [1,6,5,5]

Tags: keras

I am trying to make a CNN model for that the input is for the form `x[18324,6]`
where 18324 is the number of inputs and 6 is the size of input vector.
But I am getting the above error with this code :

```py
indata = np.loadtxt("D:\\iit ropar intern\\alllog.txt.txt",dtype='float')
x = indata[:,0:6]
y = indata[:,6:11]

print(np.shape(x))
print(x.shape[0])

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_tr ain, X_test, y_train, y_test =sk.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.10)

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

print(X_train.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=6, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
#X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],1))
history=model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=50, 
batch_size=10,validation_split=0.1,verbose=1)

scores = model.evaluate(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error originates at the second `Conv1D` because your kernel is getting bigger than the tensor dimension. To fix this, either use `padding='same'` or change `kernel_size=1` after the first `Conv1D`.